# ESP32 Arduino: Guru Meditation Error: Core 1 panic'ed (StoreProhibited)

Tags: dynamic, esp32, arduino-ide

Sending data from (mesh network)smoke sensors to AWS. I am storing the node data using linked list.After passing data to AWS,i am try to de-allocate the memory and coming across  following  two errors in *free()*.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>


          typedef struct Node 
          {
            uint8_t node_data[15];        //stores node infomation
            struct Node* next;            //pointer to next node
          }node;
          
          node *head=NULL; 
          
          node*current=NULL;

          static uint8_t k[15];              //this array keeps track of data received on UART port
          
          static uint8_t node_count=0;      //keeps the track of no. of nodes added to the system
            
          void push_data(int []);          /*this function pushes data present in  array into
                                             a node(memory allocated to node dynamically)*/

          
          void delete_node(node*);        //this function deletes the memory allocated to node
          
          void pack_data(void);          // send node data to aws
          
          void loop()
          {
              
              if(Serial2.available()>0) 
               
               {
                 
                    for( uint8_t i=0;i<15;i++)
                      {
                         k [i]= Serial2.read();
                       }
              
                    push_data(k);
               
                }
                
                delay(5000);
               
          }
          
          void push_data(uint8_t arr[])
          { 
                  if(head==NULL)
                  {   
                        head=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
                        
                        current=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
                         
                        for(uint8_t i=0;i<15;i++)
                        {
                              head->node_data[i]=arr[i];
                        }
                              
                        head->next=current;
                        
                        node_count++;
                        
                        return;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      for(uint8_t i=0;i<15;i++)
                       {    
                       current->node_data[i]=arr[i];
                       }
                                
                      current->next=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
                      
                      current=current->next;
                      
                      current->next=NULL;
                      
                      node_count++;
                      
                      pack_data();
                      
                      return; 
                  
              }
              
          }
          
          void pack_data()
          {
            /*this function converts node data into data format
             * and sends the data to aws.*/

             
             /* Once the data is send to aws ,
               the memory allocated to nodes is freed
             */
            
            delete_node(head);
            return;
            
            }
          
            void delete_node(node* n)
          {  
            node* m=NULL;
            
              while(n!=NULL)
                    { 
                       m=n->next;
                       
                      free(n);
                      
                       n=NULL;
                       
                       n = m;
                      }
                   // return;
                    
            }
```

Whenever is am trying to free the dynamically allocated memory,the **delete_node** function causes problem.Throwing the following errors
*ERROR 1*

```
assert failed: multi_heap_realloc multi_heap_poisoning.c:289 (head != NULL)
```

*ERROR 2*

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (LoadStoreError). Exception was unhandled. 
   
   Core  1 register dump:
   PC      : 0x400f3fc4  PS      : 0x00060330  A0      : 0x800efca4  A1      : 0x3ffb1920  
   A2      : 0x00000000  A3      : 0x3ffcc800  A4      : 0x00000005  A5      : 0x00000000  
   A6      : 0x00000005  A7      : 0x40000014  A8      : 0x800f3ff4  A9      : 0x3ffb1910  
   A10     : 0x3ffcc800  A11     : 0x88000028  A12     : 0x00000000  A13     : 0x3ffcc800  
   A14     : 0x00000008  A15     : 0x00000000  SAR     : 0x00000004  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000003  
   EXCVADDR: 0x4000001e  LBEG    : 0x40088f8c  LEND    : 0x40088fa2  LCOUNT  : 0xffffffff
```

Comment: Hi Ritika, welcome to SO. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You've left out the definitions and other relevant details of variables size_1 and push. Also please consider indenting your code so it becomes readable.

Comment: Seconding everything @Tarmo said. If you're not willing or not able to properly format your code yourself, search the web for "C++ code beautifier" and you'll find web sites you can copy and paste your code into that will format it for you. Properly formatted code makes it much easier to understand what the code is doing. Your code is barely readable. Also please consider using the ESP Exception Decoder](https://github.com/me-no-dev/EspExceptionDecoder) to pinpoint the line that's throwing the error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for reverting back.I have tried to make the code more readable...please answer my query. The EspExceptionDecoder points out the error in free(),which i am unable to diagnose